# Tomcat configuration for serving static content directly for Orbeon

Tags: tomcat, orbeon

[Tomcat configuration link in orbeon](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-javascript-css-resources#TOC-Examples-of-Apache-configurations) tells about how to configure tomcat to server static content like images, java-script and css directly to the client machine and remove un-necessary load from the Orbeon engine.

- The description here doesn't contain any detail, and hence I am not
  able to do the configuration.
- I would also like to know if the externalizing will work for the css and java-script in orbeon 3.9 as orbeon merges these files into a single file.

I am using tomcat 6.x and orbeon 3.9.

**Edited**

**orbeon image folder structure**`d:\Server\apache-tomcat\webapps\orbeon3.9\WEB-INF\resources\images\forms_img`

**Image URL generated by orbeon**`http://localhost:8080/orbeon3.9/images/forms_img/print.gif`

**Orbeon code for image URL**`<xhtml:img src="/images/forms_img/print.gif" />`

If anyone has successfully configured it. Please post the details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW the documentation your linking to is about using Apache Server as a front-end. The concept though should also work with the UrlRewriterFilter, as suggested by @palacsint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't move the `resources` folder and you mustn't use any Tomcat specific settings use [Tuckey Url Rewrite Filter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html). The following rule works for me, so it's able to serve content from the `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>^/images/(.*)$</from>
        <to type="forward">/WEB-INF/resources/images/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Tuckey can handle `.htaccess` files too but I haven't used it yet. Maybe the linked `.htaccess` works well with it.

---

Another solution:

I suppose you've configured the orbeon servlet in the `web.xml` with an url pattern `/` as the [documentation suggested](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/packaging-and-deployment):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>orbeon-main-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServletDelegate
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>orbeon-main-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In Tomcat the [`DefaultServlet` serves static contents](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html), set it for your static content:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    ...
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then complete the `url-pattern` list. Your linked configuration (which actually points to an Apache HTTP Server configuration, not a Tomcat configuration) is a good starting point.

Please note that these patterns are not regular regexps. Check [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/) *12.2 Specification of Mappings* for the syntax ([here is some example](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.URLPattern)).

---

Based on your edit the `servlet-mapping` should be something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/forms_img/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And you have to move the `WEB-INF/resources/images/forms_img` folder to `/images/forms_img` in your webapp (so it will be on `d:\Server\apache-tomcat\webapps\orbeon3.9\images\forms_img`) since the files under the `WEB-INF` is not available.

Comment: i checked ur configuration. But the source faced issue when i deployed. the images where looking at `http://localhost:8080/orbeon3.9/images/forms_img/print.gif` but tomcat filtered it and got a 404 error. I have updated my image location and other details in the initial question. Please let me know if some redirect can be done

Comment: Have you moved the `images` folder?

Comment: i cant move the image folder for different env. is should use the same path for tomcat and weblogic.

Comment: I see, the same war has to work on WebLogic too. Check the update please, I've added another idea.

Comment: your "another solution" works without any issue, and I am satisfied with it. **But, 1st solution is not working as you described**. The URL generated with urlredirect _localhost:8080/orbeon3.9/WEB-INF/resources/images/forms_img/print.gif_ is not directly accessible through browser. So I don't understand how it should work when my application is running. Is there some other configuration needed for this url redirect to work?

Comment: 1st is the Tuckey? `type="forward"` use an internal forward so the browsers will not see `WEB-INF` in the url. Furhermore, `WEB-INF` should not be directly accessible from a browser.